# How to take console input using scanner in Singly / Doubly Linked List in Java (without Collection)?

Tags: java, linked-list, java.util.scanner, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I want to solve some linked list questions but i am not able to take input from console, I don't know where I am doing wrong.

What am I doing wrong with my code :

```
import java.util.*;
class ScannerInputLinkedList{
    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
    }
    void insertNode(Node head, int data){
        Node curr = head;

        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.data = data;
        temp.next = null;

        while(curr.next!=null){

            curr = curr.next;
        }
        curr.next = temp;
        System.out.print(curr.data+"->");
    }
    System.out.println();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScannerInputLinkedList obj = new ScannerInputLinkedList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        int x;
        Node head = new Node();
        while(t-- > 0){
            x = sc.nextInt();
            obj.insertNode(head, x);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, whether you want to construct an linkedlist from user input and test such list?

Comment: I don't think you've ever assigned `obj.head`

Comment: @cricket_007 : didn't get it , can you help it

Comment: @Crabime : construct a linked list from user input

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Most linked list implementations maintain a head node reference within the List class rather than maintaining one Node element with links

Answer (score 0):

Just a small problem with your code. The printing statement (located above main method) is outside any method. In fact it is not needed at all. Just remove it and change System.out.print(...) to System.out.println(...) at line 19. This will make your code free of errors.

This solution was regarding your problem that you weren't able to get inputs. Apart from that, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. In case you are trying to append nodes to your linked list, you will need to recheck your logic. Your code is creating a list with already a node, appending to it but you are printing the data of node whose next is new node.

For inputs [t = 1, x = 3], your code is printing 0->. This "0" is the data of first node for the set of inputs, and your new node will be the second node.

Anyways, just for the solution to your problem of not being able to take inputs, here is the corrected code. You can use IDE's like netbeans or eclipse to quickly identify what is wrong with your code.

```
import java.util.*;
class ScannerInputLinkedList{

 static class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
}
void insertNode(Node head, int data){
    Node curr = head;

    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.data = data;
    temp.next = null;

    while(curr.next!=null){

        curr = curr.next;
    }
    curr.next = temp;
    System.out.println(curr.data+"->");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScannerInputLinkedList obj = new ScannerInputLinkedList();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    int x;
    Node head = new Node();
    while(t-- > 0){
        x = sc.nextInt();
        obj.insertNode(head, x);

    }
}
}
```